# How to find the value of the function f after applying translation on x axis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

Suppose that the function $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers. If $f (x) = |x|$ for $x ∈ [−7, 7]$ and $f(x) = f(x + 25)$ for $x ∈ R$, what is the value $f(120)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: what does $f(95)$ equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As f(120) = f(-5 + 5×25) the answer is ...

Comment: Thank you, William... I didn't notice that the function is periodic and the answer is 5.